# How do I suppress webkit messages in rspec output

Tags: rspec, webkit, capybara, retina-display, osx-mavericks

I've just moved to a macbook pro retina with Mavericks and have started getting these warning messages in my rspec output:

> webkit_server[55708:507] CoreText performance note: Client called
>   CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Arial" and got font with PostScript
>   name "ArialMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when
>   calling this API.

I'm using capybara with the webkit javascript driver by setting the following in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Does anyone know how to suppress the messages?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
brew uninstall qt && brew update && brew install qt
```

related: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/581

Comment: Just wanted to mention the version numbers-- qt 4.8.5 is the first version that is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering my own question here after finding some info from github:

This seems to be an issue seen specifically on Mavericks and is todo with one of capybara-webkit's dependancies; the capybara-webkit project are aware of it and currently have a work around available [in this issue discussion thread](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/581)

One thing to note is that the work around didn't work for me on capybara-webkit 0.14.2 so I updated to version 1.0.0 with:

> bundle update capybara-webkit

The message suppession routine work fine after that :)