# Rspec + Capybara + Poltergeist fails to submit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a form in a Rails application that uses the [tokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) jQuery plugin. In order to test the form, I have added poltergeist as the js driver and added `js: true` to the specs. However, as soon as I enable javascript on any given spec, the `click_button` action does nothing. I have placed a `puts` at the first line in the controller, and it is never executed.

The form works fine as a user in the browser, and the test executes properly without the `js: true`. However, without javascript enabled, I cannot exercise the `tokenInput` field.

There is no error message; if my test is simply:

```
spec 'test something', js: true do
  visit new_projects_path
  click_button 'Create Project'
end
```

It passes; however, the controller is never reached.

I am getting these warnings everytime I run a spec with poltergeist:

> 2013-11-05 07:39:42.087 phantomjs[5629:507] *** WARNING: Method
>   userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later.
>   It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking:
>   instead. 2013-11-05 07:39:42.502 phantomjs[5629:507] CoreText
>   performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name
>   "Times New Roman" and got font with PostScript name
>   "TimesNewRomanPSMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names
>   when calling this API. 2013-11-05 07:39:42.502 phantomjs[5629:507]
>   CoreText performance note: Set a breakpoint on
>   CTFontLogSuboptimalRequest to debug. 2013-11-05 07:39:42.588
>   phantomjs[5629:507] CoreText performance note: Client called
>   CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Times New Roman" and got font with
>   PostScript name "TimesNewRomanPSMT". For best performance, only use
>   PostScript names when calling this API. 2013-11-05 07:39:42.590
>   phantomjs[5629:507] CoreText performance note: Client called
>   CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Times New Roman" and got font with
>   PostScript name "TimesNewRomanPSMT". For best performance, only use
>   PostScript names when calling this API.

I also tried the specs with capybara-webkit, and it died a horrible death whenever it clicked the form button. It never hit the controller either.

Here is the code for `ProjectsController#new`

```
= form_for project do |f|
  %div.row
    %div.large-3.columns
      %label
        %strong Name: 
    %div.large-6.columns
      = f.text_field :name, { placeholder: "Name" }
    %div.large-3.columns
  %div.row
    %div.large-3.columns
      %label
        %strong Description: 
    %div.large-6.columns
      = f.text_area :description, { placeholder: "Description", class: "long" }
      %aside.instruction
        This field accepts Markdown formatted text
    %div.large-3.columns
  %div.row
    %div.large-3.columns
      %label
        %strong Short Description:
    %div.large-6.columns
      = f.text_area :short_description, { placeholder: "Short Description", class: "short"}
    %div.large-3.columns
  %div.row
    %div.large-3.columns
      %label
        %strong Source:
    %div.large-6.columns
      =f.text_field :source, { placeholder: "Link to source or \"Closed\"" }
    %div.large-3.columns
  %div.row
    %div.large-3.columns
      %label
        %strong Technologies:
    %div.large-6.columns
      = f.text_field :technology_tokens, data: { load: @project.technologies }
    %div.large-3.columns
  %div.row
    %div.large-6.large-centered.small-6.small-centered.columns
      = f.submit
```

Ruby 2, Rails 4, OS X Mavericks

Comment: Hi,

Regarding those warnings, I had something very similar when using capybara on a MacOS Mavericks platform, but managed to get a work around. Here's the info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19753928/632735

Comment: please try the capybara debugging tips mentioned here: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to capybara-webkit, and it worked this time. I don't believe I changed anything; it's possible something updated and it was a brief incompatibility?

I'm pretty sure the warnings are a Qt thing; they started showing up for everyone recently. I just thought I'd include them in case I was missing something inside them.